# DIV won't center

Tags: css, html, center

Im having difficulty horizontally centering two adjacent DIV's.  The two divs "JoinSub" within their parent "JoinSubWrap" currently float left and not centering.  The parent div has margin o auto which I thought would center both parent and children.

here's my HTML

```
<div id=JoinSubfooter> 
    <div id="JoinSubfooter-wrapper">
        <div id="subft-line"></div>
        <div id="JoinSft-msg-block">Some Text Goes Here</div>

        <div id="JoinSubWrap">
            <div id="JoinSub">
                <h2>Title 1</h2>
                <p>message goes here</p>
            </div>

            <div id="JoinSub">
                <h2>Title 2</h2>
                <p>message goes here</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Here's my CSS

```
#JoinSubfooter {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background: transparent url(../images/grey_body_noise.png);
    clear: both;/*Clears all columns and sets the footer at the bottom*/
}

#JoinSubfooter-wrapper {
    width:981px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
    text-align:center;
}

#JoinSft-msg-block {
    background: transparent url(../images/grey_opaque_pixel.png);
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    display:inline-block;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 30px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
}

#JoinSubWrap {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#JoinSub {
    float:left;
    margin: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px 12px 12px 12px;
    width: 200px;
    border-right: solid #666666 1px;  
}

#JoinSub:last-child {
    border: 0px;
}

#JoinSub h2{
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Setting auto margins will centre a block element, but it won't cause it to shrink-wrap its children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#JoinSubWrap {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table; 
}
```

Add `display:table`.

http://jsfiddle.net/Eq5gL/

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly.  I havent seen that CSS before.  For my learning what does it do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this mate:

```
<div id=JoinSubfooter> 
    <div id="JoinSubfooter-wrapper">
        <div id="subft-line"></div>
        <div id="JoinSft-msg-block">Some Text Goes Here</div>

    <div id="JoinSubWrap">
        <div class="JoinSub">
            <h2>Title 1</h2>
            <p>message goes here</p>
        </div>

        <div class="JoinSub">
            <h2>Title 2</h2>
            <p>message goes here</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    </div>
    </div>
```

and css

```
  #JoinSubfooter {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background: transparent url(../images/grey_body_noise.png);
  clear: both;/*Clears all columns and sets the footer at the bottom*/
}

  #JoinSubfooter-wrapper {
  width:981px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
  text-align:center;
}

  #JoinSft-msg-block {
  background: transparent url(../images/grey_opaque_pixel.png);
  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  display:inline-block;
  font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size:24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 30px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  }

  #JoinSubWrap {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align:center;
  }

  .JoinSub {
  margin: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px 12px 12px 12px;
  width: 200px;
  border-right: solid #666666 1px;  
   margin: 0 auto;  
    overflow:hidden;
    display:inline-block;
  }

  #JoinSub:last-child {
  border: 0px;
  }

  #JoinSub h2{
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  }
```

And fiddle link:
http://jsfiddle.net/mu42P/

Comment: This is a massive wall of code. Why didn't the original code work? What have you changed? Why would that fix it?

Comment: thanks.  Why did the change from an ID to a Class work.  Many thanks.

Comment: I did some changed other than changing id to class :P

I removed float:left; from JoinSub and added display:inline-block; then added text-align:center; on JoinSubWrap.

Using ids in many elements is not a good tactic generally. Ids should be more exclusive, nothing changes but its better to use class for many elements.

Peace out.

Comment: Also I would like to add because @Quentin asked that adding display:inline-block to an element makes it behave as it is text. Then with a simple text-align:center to the parent element you can move it wherever you want!